# 'Variable symbols' in definition of $\mathcal{L}$-terms in model theory

Tags: logic, definition, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a language. In David Marker's *Model Theory: An Introduction*, the set of *$\mathcal{L}$-terms* is defined to be the smallest set $\mathcal{T}$ containing all of the constant symbols of $\mathcal{L}$, the 'variable symbols' $v_1$, $v_2$,... and such that for each function symbol $f$ (in $\mathcal{L}$) and $t_1,...t_{n_f}\in\mathcal{T}$ (where $n_f$ is the positive integer associated to $f$), we must have that $f(t_1,...,t_{n_f})\in\mathcal{T}$.

I'm a little puzzled about where these 'variable symbols' have come from. A *language* is defined on the previous page to consist of *function symbols*, *relation symbols* and *constant symbols*, yet there is no mention of 'variable symbols' as being in any way intrinsic to the language $\mathcal{L}$.

Am I right in thinking that for each language $\mathcal{L}$, there is an associated sequence of variable symbols $(v_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, and that this is what is being referred to in the definition of the $\mathcal{L}$-terms? If so, then I don't understand why it would not be part of the definition of the language, like the other symbols.

Many thanks

Comment: The $v_i$ don't depend in any way on $\mathcal{L}$. You could use the same set of variables to form the terms over any language. The variables come in as part of the definition of $\mathcal{T}$. (And likewise equality and the connectives and quantifiers come in as part of the definition of $\mathcal{L}$-formulas as explained by Marker just before the definition of $\mathcal{L}$-terms.)

Comment: @Rob Arthan The definition insists that $\mathcal{T}$ *contains* the sequence $v_i$, so surely it must already be understood what the sequence $v_i$ is independently of $\mathcal{T}$? It seems a bit like saying 'the smallest closed set containing the set $A$' without first stating what $A$ is.

Comment: It explains this before the definition of $\mathcal{L}$-terms. It says "Formulas are strings of symbols built using the symbols of $\mathcal{L}$, variable symbols $v_1, v_2, \ldots$, the equality symbol =, ...". The variables just give a countably infinite supply of symbols that are distinct from all the other symbols.

Comment: So this sequence of variable symbols can be considered fixed and used in complete generality as simply a list of symbols to draw upon wherever needed to form 'terms', in exactly the same way as 'there exists', '=', 'for all', etc.?

Comment: That's right. All that matters is that they can be distinguished from each other and from all the other types of symbol.

Comment: Having said that, are **all** symbols (function/relation/constant/variable) implicitly assumed to be mutually distinguishable? It doesn't say that but it seems like it should be the case.

Comment: That is the simplest assumption to make and I am sure it is what Marker has in mind. In practice, we do overload symbols, e.g., + in the language of vector spaces, but it's simplest to explain that away as a shorthand for an unambiguous underlying representation.

Comment: They are part of the first-order language specification: connectives, quantifiers, variables, equality. The specific language of a theory $T$ adds to them non-logical symbols: functions, relations, constants.